# MQ message received as byte array instead of String

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am using Websphere MQ and reading messages from the queue using Spring integration and a jms adapter.

When I manually add messages to the queue the application is reading them and reading the data as a `String` and everything is fine.

However, when an external party is adding messages to the queue the application is reading them as a byte array and then throwing this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

The messages look the same to me in MQExplorer.

Although I have noticed a Format column, where the messages that are being processed as Strings have the value `MQSTR` and the message being processed as a Byte[] has nothing in there. Could this be related? If so any ideas how to set the "format" of the message?

Does anybody know what determines the payload content type of a message, that way I may be able to recreate the issue at least?

Comment: What version of Websphere MQ are you using?

Comment: @JoseChavez I think 7.0.1, but that is only based off of MQ Explorer, is there another way to find out? (I dont have access to the boxes the queue is running on)

Comment: You may have to ask your sysadmin. But I've provided an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've encountered this kind of situation before. The external party may not be using JMS, but may be using the MQI or the Websphere MQ classes for Java.

This means that you may be receiving the messages as ByteMessages.

[This article](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/jm25524_.htm) explains the conversion of MQ messages to JMS messages.

I would talk to the external party and ask them how they are sending their messages. They may have to give you details of the MQMD properties they are setting. You may have to retrieve these in your MessageListener.

Comment: Thanks, This is useful. By changing my test to send a message with this type `Message<byte[]>` I am able to reproduce the error, I will probably just add a transformer in so I can handle String and byte[] messages.

Comment: Glad it helped! Yes I tried converting some of our processes to using JMS from the MQ API, but I still am working out the kinks. Our external clients use the MQ API and sometimes they are sending us mainframe messages using EBCDIC!

Answer (score 1):

On native MQ message sender side, set the mqmd["Format"] = 'MQSTR' will make sure the message is sent in jms_text format, otherwise by default it's in bytes format.

I got it working in Python2.7 with Pymqi.